# Discord.js interaction.member.permissions.has is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "Ban user.",
    options: [
        {
            name: "user",
            description: "Type user nickname",
            type: 6,
            required: true,
        },
    ],
    async execute(client, say, interaction, args) {
        if(!interaction.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            console.log("works now...")
        }
    },
};
```

Error:

```
TypeError: interaction.member.permissions.has is not a function
```

What is wrong with this? Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your command handler as the issue might be because of the ordering of the arguments passed in

Comment: try console.log(interaction.member) and see what it is, you might have done a bad order of the arguments in the execute function for example switching "interaction" and "say"